# Do threads run synchronously when calling execute() multiple times on one AsyncTask instance

Tags: java, multithreading, android-asynctask

So I have this bgTask class that extends AsyncTask, and I call the constructor once. But then I call bgTask.execute() inside a for loop. Do the threads run synchronously in this case? And I do use the onPostExecute method inside the class.

```
BgTask bgTask = new BgTask();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   bgTask.execute();
}
```

Comment: You obviously haven't even tried to run this, because per [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), `The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you call execute it runs the AsyncTask immediately.  If you need a group of threads to behave a certain way then I would suggest reviewing Java's [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) specifically [Thread Pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).